# Multiplying columns based on class

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas-groupby

I want to multiply two columns but only if they belong to a particular class.

I have tried multiplying the columns based on a condition as shown below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'Values':[1,1,1],'Class':[0,1,0],'Weights':[0.8,0.9,0.7]}
dataset = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
print(dataset)

(dataset[dataset['Class']==1])['Values'] = (dataset[dataset['Class']==1])['Values']*dataset['Weights']

print(dataset)
```

but this wouldn't change the dataset.

then I tried this:

```
d = {'Values':[1,1,1],'Class':[0,1,0],'Weights':[0.8,0.9,0.7]}
dataset = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
print(dataset)

dataset['Weights'] = dataset['Weights']*dataset['Class']
replace_weights = {0:1}
dataset['Weights'] = dataset['Weights'].replace(replace_weights)

dataset['Values'] = dataset['Values']*dataset['Weights']

print(dataset)
```

this is giving me the expected result, but I wished to knew if there's a simpler or more elegant way of doing this?

my input dataframe was:

```
   Values  Class  Weights
0       1      0      0.8
1       1      1      0.9
2       1      0      0.7
```

and the output dataframe is:

```
   Values  Class  Weights
0     1.0      0      1.0
1     0.9      1      0.9
2     1.0      0      1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

In Pandas, you have to use the loc function when you want to change the value of a slice of a DataFrame. Otherwise your code is right.

To go back to your code :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'Values':[1,1,1],'Class':[0,1,0],'Weights':[0.8,0.9,0.7]}
dataset = pd.DataFrame(data = d)

print(dataset)

Class  Values  Weights
    0      0       1      0.8
    1      1       1      0.9
    2      0       1      0.7

dataset.loc[dataset['Class']==1, 'Values'] = dataset[dataset['Class']==1]['Values']*dataset['Weights']

print(dataset)

   Class  Values  Weights
0      0     1.0      0.8
1      1     0.9      0.9
2      0     1.0      0.7
```

Comment: You should only edit your questions to clarify what you want to say. If you have annother question post annother one, don't edit your question to transform it into annother one. Otherwise answers that have already been posted (like mine) become obsolete..

Comment: You are right . I have edited the question again to improve it. Thanks .